# how to view all the methods in a class in swift at runtime without using objective-c libraries

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, reflection, introspection

I want to get the list of methods present in a class and their arguments list at runtime. I dont want to use any Objective-C runtime methods such as **`class_copyMethodList`**, can this be done using Mirror(reflecting: any) or any similar methods. I tried using [wickwirew/Runtime](https://github.com/wickwirew/Runtime) but was not able to find a way to get the methods present in a class.

an example for the class to Introspect be a simple math class but in reality, this may be any class **which is not NSObject compatible**, and also which I cannot modify.

```
  import Foundation

 class Maths
{
    func add(a:Int,b:Int)->Int{
        return a + b
    }

    func sub(a:Int,b:Int)->Int{
        return a - b
    }

    func append(a:String,b:String)->String{
        return a + b
    }
}
```

at runtime I just want to get the list of methods like  add ,sub, append and the type of arguments that they accept.

thank you.